# brackets () in java script calculator?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have created a javascript calculator.this is an image of it

[image]

But am facing a problem with brackets (). and the dot (.)

what i want is that when i click on the bracket button first it will give me an open bracket then if i click again it should give a closing bracket and so on like in a normal calculator i want the program to know how to deal with brackets.

```
<input type="text" id="t1" class="tt">
<input type="button" onClick="myFun6()" value="()">
<input type="button" onClick="myFun7()" value=".">

<script>
function myFun6()
{

var prac = "()";
document.getElementById("t1").value+=prac;

}
</script>
```

my second question is for the dot. i manged to get work but i still have an issue. if you click on the dot button if there was no element it will give "0." but if i click again the result will be "0.0." and so on.

```
function myFun7()
{


var d=document.getElementById("t1").value;

if(d.length - 1)
{
    d="0.";
    document.getElementById("t1").value+=d;
}
else
{
    d=".";
    document.getElementById("t1").value+=d;
}

}
```

Comment: So, no nested parentheses using your calculator…?

Comment: Normal calculators have got two buttons for each open and close bracket.

Comment: Instead of having same button for `(` and `)`. You can have two separate buttons one for `(` and other for `)`.

Comment: ```if(d.length - 1)``` equals ```if (d.length != 1)```, so if you click dot button when the value is `1` or `2`, it will be `0.`, not `1.` and `2.`

Comment: If you want to use a single button opening and closing brackets, you'll have to do a bit of state management: if the last pressed button was an operator, or if you are at the start of your expression, then issue an open parentheses; otherwise, if the last pressed button was a digit, then you close the parentheses; you may have to test for a few edge cases here and there, though. Just try to think about when a opening/closing parentheses would make sense depending on the current state of the calculator.

Comment: @O.o my phone calculator doesn't!! and i have tried to add different buttons but i want to know if i can do it in the same button.

Comment: Which framework do you use? I think `redux` is the best solution.

Comment: @O.o im using basic java script

Comment: It's okay. You can use sessionStorage as well. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a single button for the "()":
A simple solution would be to create a switch that would alternate whether or not a open or close is needed.

```
    let bracketSwitch = false;

    function myFun6(){
        var prac;
        if(!bracketSwitch){
            prac = "("
        } else {
            prac = ")"
        };
        bracketSwitch = !bracketSwitch;
        document.getElementById("t1").value+=prac;
    }
```

As mentioned above you could store the switch in local or session storage as well.

Though this simple solution probably isn't what you really want. As @deceze mentioned this would not allow for nested parentheses...

You would have to include some heavier logic to allow for nested parentheses.
here is something I came up with. This probably doesn't quite get all edge cases and there are certainly other (better) ways of doing it... But this would at least get you started:

```
let bracketSwitch = false;
function myFun6_2(){
    var input = document.getElementById("t1").value;

    if(input.length >= 1){ //already something in the input box
        var index = input.charAt(input.length-1);

        if(!isNaN(parseInt(index)) && bracketSwitch){ //index is a number
            document.getElementById("t1").value += ')';
            bracketSwitch = !bracketSwitch;
        } else if((!isNaN(parseInt(index)) && !bracketSwitch) || index === "."){
            document.getElementById("t1").value += 'x(';
            bracketSwitch = !bracketSwitch;
        }else {
            document.getElementById("t1").value += '(';
            if(!bracketSwitch){ //if the switch was off
                bracketSwitch = !bracketSwitch;
            };
        }
    } else { //empty input box
        document.getElementById("t1").value += '(';
        bracketSwitch = !bracketSwitch;
    }
};
```

Of note to this else block:

```
else if((!isNaN(parseInt(index)) && !bracketSwitch) || index === "."){
    document.getElementById("t1").value += 'x(';
    bracketSwitch = !bracketSwitch;
```

On the calculator on my phone if I have "5" and hit the parentheses it adds "X(". Giving an end result of "5x(". Or if I have "5." it gives "5.x(".
You may not want to do the same on yours. I could also argue that there shouldn't be any parentheses added in these situations.

The switch works well as long as the user doesn't backspace past a point that the switch was previously changed. Some additional logic would be needed here to make sure the switch is in the proper position. The switch also needs to be reset if the "c" button is hit.

---

As for the dot problem:
As mentioned in a comment above, your code would replace any single value entered with "0." Here is a solution that seems to do what you are wanting.

```
function myFun7(){
    var d=document.getElementById("t1").value;
    var dot = d.includes('.');
    if(d.length === 0){
        document.getElementById("t1").value+= "0.";
    } else if(!dot){ //this checks to make sure only one dot has been used
        document.getElementById("t1").value+= ".";
    }


}
```